# sql: selecting rows, in which some values are equal (not all)

Tags: sql, db2

Pre-condition:

Table, like

```
id value1 value2 value3
1   x       y      z
2   x       y      x 
3   x       z      y
4   y       x      z
5   x       x      z
```

Task: make query, which will select all rows, in which "pairs" (value1 and value2) are equal by rows (e.g. for our case result should be 1st and second row:

```
  id value1 value2 value3
    1   x       y      z
    2   x       y      x
```

We do NOT know, what values could be in the table.

So, this is the point.

Comment: what did you try so far? why not 3rd and 5th row in the expected result?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: relational, seems db2

Comment: @Jorge Campos: equal values from different rows. for example, Jorge Campos JR and Jorge Campos SR should be in result of query, but but Jorge CampoSSS JR - NO.

Comment: Why not the rows with 3 and 5 also?

Comment: I Asked just because He didn't add the rows 3 and 5 so it was not defined properly!

Comment: sorry guys, mistype. will fix 3 or 5 for avoiding misunderstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value1, t1.value2
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.value1 = t2.value1 AND t1.value2 = t2.value2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by value1, value2) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
 where cnt >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where id in
(
  select id
  from your_table
  group by value1, value2
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Only by the first two values.

Comment: Thanks. Did not see that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from Table t1, Table t2
where t1.value1 =t2.value1
and t1.value2=t2.value2
and t1.id<>t2.id
and t1.value1 <>t1.value2
```